# I have one big query for performance related in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have one big query for performance related in SQL Server 2005.

I have data like this

```
id  parentId
1   null
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   4
6   3
```

I want the order for the records by downline with parentId and id wise
like

```
id  Order
1   1
2   2
4   3
5   4
3   5
4   6
```

I don't want to use loop, because loop is creating the problem if high number of rows.
Please give me easy way to do it and hurting performance.

Updated,
Please run the script below

create table [mytable]
(
[id] int,
[parentId] int
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(2,6)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(4,9)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(5,4)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(6,13)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(7,13)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(8,5)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(9,1)
INSERT INTO [mytable] ([id],[parentId])VALUES(13,1)
GO

; WITH    q AS 
        ( 
        SELECT  id, parentId, CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' AS path 
        FROM    mytable 
        WHERE   parentId IS NULL 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT  t.id, t.parentId, q.path + CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' 
        FROM    q 
        JOIN    mytable t 
        ON      t.parentId = q.id 
        ) 
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY path) AS rn 
FROM    q 
ORDER BY 
        path 
GO

The result of this query
ID    ParentId  Path     rn
1   NULL    1/       1
13  1   1/13/       2
6   13  1/13/6/      3
2   6   1/13/6/2/    4
7   13  1/13/7/      5
9   1   1/9/         6
4   9   1/9/4/       7
5   4   1/9/4/5/     8
8   5   1/9/4/5/8/   9

But i want the result for rn from avove result first 1 then 1/9 then1/9/... then 1/13/ then 1/13/... .Please give me the solution for that.

I want result like

```
ID    ParentId  Path     rn 
1   NULL    1/       1 
13  1   1/13/       6 
6   13  1/13/6/      7 
2   6   1/13/6/2/    8
7   13  1/13/7/      9
9   1   1/9/         2 
4   9   1/9/4/       3 
5   4   1/9/4/5/     4 
8   5   1/9/4/5/8/   5
```

---

```
WITH    q AS 
        ( 
        SELECT  id, parentId, CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS path 
        FROM    mytable 
        WHERE   parentId IS NULL 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT  t.id, t.parentId, q.path + '/' + CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        FROM    q 
        JOIN    mytable t 
        ON      t.parentId = q.id 
        ) 
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY path) AS rn 
FROM    q 
ORDER BY 
        path
```

In above 
Have one more question.
you are using the order by path
suppose,in the case of the records like 1/13 and 1/2 , so order by is comming 1/13 and 1/2, but i want the order 1/2 and then 1/13 , because 2 is less then 13.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your expected results. Should the last ID be 6 instead of 4?

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  id, parentId, CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/' AS path
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   parentId IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.id, t.parentId, q.path + CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '/'
        FROM    q
        JOIN    mytable t
        ON      t.parentId = q.id
        )
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY path) AS rn
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        path
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little I'm confused as to where you got this from based on the question at hand.

Comment: @msarchet: this is a hierarchy presented as adjacency list. The @op wants to find each entry's position in the tree order.

Comment: Have one more question.
you are using the order by path
in the case of the records like 1/13 and 1/2 , so order by is comming 1/13 and 1/2, but i want the order 1/2 and then 1/13 , because 2 is less then 13.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what your database looks like but something like this should work

```
Select id, [Order] From Table1 Order By Order, id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, parentid as order from table 
order by coalesce(parentid, 9999), id
```